# java regex transformation

Tags: java

During my searching, I would like a piece of advice :

I'd like to transform this, with replace method :

```
"labels": "\"label_name\": \"Webapp\","
```

to :

```
"labels": ["Webapp"]
```

in java. In fact, I'm embarrassed  with `"\" \"`.

If someone could me suggest me something.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`replace` can't use regex, but you can use `replaceAll`:

```
String input = "\"labels\": \"\\\"label_name\\\": \\\"Webapp\\\",\"";

String result = input.replaceAll(
    "(\"\\w+\")\\s*:[^:]+:\\s*\\\\\\\"(\\w+)\\\\\\\",\"", 
    "$1: \\[\"$2\"\\]");

System.out.println(result1); // "labels": ["Webapp"]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks mates, It works like a charm ! Please if you have a little time, could you explain me the complete sense of the regex ? I am looking here now : ... . If I understand I will put the description.

Comment: @Ale Regex101 does a good job of explaining: https://regex101.com/r/UVqVYo/1 (see on the right). You just have to un-escape some things. The `$1` and `$2` are referencing the capture groups from the first argument.

Comment: Wow so cool .. I have just seen the website ! It is marvellous Thanks dude !